# Is it possibel to send a CLI command from a input on the GPIO

Tags: gpio, terminal

Im a beginner in raspberry, and i would like to send a command on the CLI whenever a input is activated on a pin.

Basically i want to push a button on a breakoutboard or similar, that sends a signal to a raspberry and then the raspberry should send a command via the terminal to a infrared transmitter connected to the raspberry, changing channel on a tv.

Its because i want to build a universal remote that can be activated by large buttons for my grandmother. I found a guide to build a universal remote that is controlled using a webpage, but i was hoping i could combine it.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Yes.  If you do a search you will find lots of examples.  Choose one.  If it doesn't work show us what you did.

Comment: I tried searching for it before i made this post. can you guide me to what to search for?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your question.  Could you edit your question and clarify what you mean by "send a command on the CLI whenever a input is activated on a pin".  Perhaps by giving examples.

Comment: I have tried to explain it better now. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: That seems to be asking how do I run a command in response to a GPIO input.  Have you tried searching for that?

Comment: No, i will try that, thanks alot

Comment: You are asking how to do A and B and C. This is not how to write a program. Figure out how to do A, B & C first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, of many examples, how to listen for the push of a button and take action

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO # Import Raspberry Pi GPIO library
def button_callback(channel):
    print("Button was pushed!")
GPIO.setwarnings(False) # Ignore warning for now
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) # Use physical pin numbering
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN) # Set pin 10 to be an input pin and set initial value to be pulled low (off)
GPIO.add_event_detect(10,GPIO.RISING,callback=button_callback) # Setup event on pin 10 rising edge
message = input("Press enter to quit\n\n") # Run until someone presses enter
GPIO.cleanup() # Clean up
```

You can see the full tutorial [here](https://raspberrypihq.com/use-a-push-button-with-raspberry-pi-gpio/)